# Location don't work on real device

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to show via toast a message with my latitude and longitude informations, so i wrote this code in my mainActivity:

```
public class RunActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_run);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude : "+location.getLatitude()+", Longitude : "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider+" is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider+" is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

}

I launch it directly on my device (Samsung S5) but toasts won't show. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting a gps fix? Hold your device outside a window for a few seconds. Don't drop it ;)

Comment: I spent the night walking as a fool in the neighborhood :D Doesn't work :(

Comment: The part where you handle missing permissions is empty. You just return. If you are using android 6, make sure, you granted permissions manually in the app settings

Comment: since i'm using only the GPS provider i used this as permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> and i use android 5 on my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by creating another project based on some informations that i got in a book so i just post my code here hoping that it will help someone. It's fully functionnal :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView Long;
public TextView Lat;
public TextView Speed;
public TextView Alt;
public TextView Clock;
public TextView Provider;
public String ProviderName;

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Provider = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Provider);
        Long = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lon);
        Lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lat);
        Speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Speed);
        Alt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Alt);
        Clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
        Provider.setText(ProviderName);
        Long.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
        Lat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        Speed.setText(Float.toString(location.getSpeed()));
        Alt.setText(Double.toString(location.getAltitude()));
        Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
        DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
        Clock.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider + " is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider + " is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationProvider provider = lm.getProvider("gps");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    ProviderName = provider.getName();


}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Marshmallow, the user has to grant permissions on runtime (not when installing, like before). In your snippet, the code to handle that permission request is empty

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
```

So return is called just before `requestLocationUpdates`. That is, why it is not called.

**Quick fix**: Go to your smartphones settings. Go to Apps, look for your app, and grant permissions manually.

**On the long run** you will need to implement that `TODO` you got in your code. See google [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

**EDIT**
I just saw your real problem here... You simply forgot to call `show()` on that toast.

```
Toast.makeText().show();
```

Comment: I added show() method to my toasts, now i get a message when i enable or disable the GPS but anything about my laitutde and longitude. 
I also checked in my Apps configuration if the permission is set for my app and yes it was already. So yeah still nothing about my geo information

Comment: I guess you are not getting a gps fix for some reason. do you have another device to test on?